# problem with 'error: expected class-name before '{' token 5 | class Solid : public Block{'

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've run into a problem that's really annoying and bothering me. This is the code:

block.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include "../global/global.hpp"

class Block{
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Rect position;
    public:
    void setTexture(SDL_Texture* _texture);
    void setPosition(SDL_Rect _position);
    void render();
    void destroy();
};
```

block.cpp:

```
#include "block.hpp"

void Block::setTexture(SDL_Texture* _texture){
    texture = _texture;
}

void Block::setPosition(SDL_Rect _position){
    position = _position;
}

void Block::render(){
    SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer,texture,nullptr,&position);
}
```

solid.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include "block.hpp"

class Solid : public Block{
    public:
    Solid();
    void setPosition(SDL_Rect _position);
    void render();
};
```

solid.cpp:

```
#include "solid.hpp"

Solid::Solid(){
    Block::setTexture(g_assets.textures["cegla"]);
}

void Solid::setPosition(SDL_Rect _position){
    Block::setPosition(_position);
}

void Solid::render(){
    Block::render();
}
```

Error:

```
In file included from src/block/../global/../block/blocks.hpp:3,
                 from src/block/../global/../map.hpp:8,
                 from src/block/../global/../assetmanager.hpp:9,
                 from src/block/../global/global.hpp:6,
                 from src/block/block.hpp:6,
                 from src/block/block.cpp:1:
src/block/../global/../block/solid.hpp:5:27: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
    5 | class Solid : public Block{
```

Please help.I don't know what could be the reason, I tried replacing #include "block.hpp" with class Block, nothing helped

Comment: What is `global.hpp`? Does it by any chance `#include "block.hpp"` or `solid.hpp`?

Comment: No need to include iostream in Block.hpp.

Comment: looks like circular dependencies. The code you show us did not contain the problem. I expect that some files in the include order higher than block.hpp include solid.hpp.

Comment: You're including unnecessary headers in headers, which often leads to cicularity problems. For instance, "block.hpp" does not need "../global/global.hpp" or <iostream>. The former should be in "block.cpp", the latter shouldn't be included there at all.

Comment: I expect your bug is a circular header loop caused by: `#include "../global/global.hpp"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Answer (score 2):

The include chain displayed in the compile error tells us what's wrong.

`block.hpp` includes `global.hpp` which includes `assetmanager.hpp` which include `map.hpp` which includes `blocks.hpp` which includes `solid.hpp` which includes `block.hpp`.

But this very last include is already in the include chain, so it is ignored by the `#pragma once`. This means that when the compiler gets to the `Solid` class definition, it hasn't seen the `Block` class definition yet, which leads to the error you're getting.

You need to reorganize and clean up your headers.